# QPersistentModelIndex from QModelIndex

Tags: qt, qml

If I have a `QList<QPersistentModelIndex>` and a function which gets a list of `QModelIndex` like this:

```
Q_INVOKABLE void storeSelection(const QModelIndexList& list) {
        _selectedIndices.clear();
        _selectedIndices.reserve(list.size());
        for(int i=0;i<list.count();i++) {
            _selectedIndices.append(QPersistentModelIndex(list[i]));
        }
    }
```

do I need to create do `QPersistentModelIndex(list[i])` in the append or could I simply append the `list[i]` and it is automatically converted to a `QPersistentModelIndex`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*QPersistentModelIndex* class has a constructor which takes a *const QModelIndex* reference ([here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qpersistentmodelindex.html#QPersistentModelIndex) the documentation).

Hence, there is no need to explicitly call the constructor:

```
_selectedIndices.append(list[i]);
```

and

```
_selectedIndices.append(QPersistentModelIndex(list[i]));
```

should be equivalent.